# Docusign authentication type for polling

Tags: docusignapi

I am using an authorization code grant to create envelopes and listen events from webhook.
But I would like to use polling too.

Is the code grant Authentification a good solution to perform polling or I need to implement a JWT grant in addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling is usually not a good idea.
It's an inefficient use of resources.
If you poll too frequently, you may be making thousands of unnecessary API calls.
If you poll less frequently, your app may not be freshly updated.
It is therefore a better idea to use a webhook.
DocuSign Connect can be used to inform your app when something happened. For example, an envelope was signed. And this way, you will be updated momentarily, and you wouldn't have to make any additional API calls.
More information here:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect

Now since I didn't really answer your question (for a good reason). You can do polling with Auth Code Grant or JWT etc. doesn't matter.
you may run into issues when you try to go-live though, so again, see my recommendation above.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Authorization Code Grant for polling, I would recommend the use of the `extended` scope in addition to `signature`. With `extended` you can keep generating new refresh tokens so that your authentication doesn't expire after 30 days.

Of course, Inbar outlines while polling in general is not a great idea.